# detecting coins in my wallet

Tags: ledger-nano-s

I have a ledger nano s and it shows up as new wallet and ethereum app online when its plugged in but I'm not sure how I can tell if anythings going in it. I am disgustingly new at this and trying to learn as fast as I can and still maintain control in my life with my responsibilities. I'm running 2 MSI radeon rx 570 8gb gddr5 soon to be 3 I'm not sure how long it will take to pull in a coin and I believe I am in the dwarf pool